# textbox matching pattern from database table

Tags: vb.net, t-sql, sql-like

I have a name textbox and I want to find any names included in the typed text in the database table patient details name column. I know how to use LIKE operator if you know the letters you want the search to start/end with etc. but this time I want textbox. I think my issue is with the quotations; I tried to play around with it but it didn't work!

```
From x in PatientDetails where ( x.Patient_Name Like  '%" Textbox1.Text "%' )
```

For example: If a Patient name in the database is: John Matt

and a user typed Matt, the above record for John Matt should be returned.

P.S I tried looking it up in Google but it mostly discuss characters not entered text box
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do

C#

```
var query = (from x in PatientDetails
             where x.Patient_Name.Contains(Textbox1.Text)
             select x).ToList();
```

VB.NET - Converted using [CodeConverter](http://converter.telerik.com/)

```
Dim query = (From x In PatientDetails Where 
             x.Patient_Name.Contains(Textbox1.Text)x).ToList()
```

Comment: Never knew about this way! Very simple and works great. Thank you loads! :)

Comment: To added knowledge, instead of `Contains` you can also use `StartsWith` & `EndsWith` - as the name suggest, no explanation needed for that :)